# Starting to learn to create iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, macos

Well I'd like to create apps for the iPhone, starting out with really really basic stuff and working up, but I don't have a Mac at the moment (well I do but it's a powerPC ibook G4, which you can't develop on) and before I invest I'd like to learn how to create apps.

I also read an article in a newspaper about how a guy starting creating apps (before Apple launched the app store) on his PC for the jailbroken iphones, then when Apple launched the app store he switched to created "legal" apps. (the article said he carried on using his PC but I'm not sure that thats true).

I'd like to do a similar thing, but I don't care about releasing any app to the jail broken iphones, I just want to learn on a PC and then I can decide to sell my ibook and save up for a Mac.

But I don't want to go out buy a Mac (expensive) and then find it's to hard for me to understand and have wasted £500 or whatever.

Comment: A Mac mini costs $599 which is significantly less than £500.

Comment: Your question should probably be "How to start learning to create iphone apps on a PC". Until you find a answer, you might want to check Stanford University online course on iPhone apps development: http://news.stanford.edu/news/2009/april1/free-iphone-software-development-course-apple-040109.html

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Free Stanford iPhone Dev Course**

> The 10-week course, iPhone Application Programming, is a hot ticket. It begins today and videos of the classes will be posted at Stanford on iTunes U two days after each class meeting (http://itunes.stanford.edu). Copies of the slides shown in class will be available there as well.
>
> http://news.stanford.edu/news/2009/april1/free-iphone-software-development-course-apple-040109.html

*(channeling for qux who pointed this out in a comment)*

Comment: Does it matter that i'm not in the US? and it might sound like a stupid question but it is a virtual class correct?

Comment: @Jonathan: Nope, doesn't matter that you're not in the US, as long as wherever you are you have access to the iTunes Music Store. It's available, free, under iTunes University. (I should have mentioned this resource too -- it was one of the first I'd started using.)

Comment: @JohnRudy hey John. I'm a self taught Ruby on Rails developer (currently a junior web developer now), and I'm hoping to start learning iOS. For someone who doesn't know any low level languages (I know some Python, Ruby, Rails, HTML, CSS, a little jQuery), how long do you think it'll take to learn iOS?

Answer (score 5):

My sincere recommendation is to spend some time with XCode on your current iBook, and get comfortable with some Mac development in general.

iPhone and Mac development use many similar libraries (although obviously UI is completely different), and if you're well-versed in one, getting up to speed on the other isn't tremendously difficult.

This will let you know whether to invest in an Intel-based Mac and continue onto iPhone development.

XCode should have come with your Mac on the installation discs. You'll need to use that copy, because the one at http://developer.apple.com is Intel-only.

For getting started books, I recommend Aaron Hillegass's excellent [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213149).

If you go with sberry2A's recommendation of a hackintosh, then you can jump right into iPhone development, and can get the dev tools from Apple. Going this route, I **still** recommend the Hillegass book, and then supplement that with [iPhone SDK Application Development](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596523190) by Jonathan Zdziarski.

If you're going to be focused primarily on Games, and already are fairly comfortable with C, instead of either of the above books, go directly to [iPhone Game Development](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596159863) by Paul Zirkle and Joe Hogue. (I'm currently working through this one.)

Comment: +1 great resources John - out of interest, have you released any apps on the App Store?

Comment: @alex: Nope. One day. One day. :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, prior to iPhone SDK 3.0, the SDK's were (inofficially) compatible with PowerPC. See [iPhone SDK on PowerPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537018/iphone-sdk-on-powerpc).

As you already have an iBook G4, you could as well put Xcode on it (you can get the Mac SDKs - even for PowerPC - for free from Apple). Then try to write some Mac apps, as the Mac and iPhone APIs are very similar. If you like one of them, you'll most probably be happy with the other, too.

Answer (score 1):

Already asked before:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718401/develop-iphone-apps-on-a-non-mac-system

[iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Basically, you can develop on Windows, but it's a slow pain in the ass.

See e.g. here: http://www.chemlab.org/2009/02/20/scrap-the-mac-leave-the-os and **detailed guide on how to do it** here: [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine#28573)