# What steps do i need to take to start developing iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Start learning to create iphone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089186/how-to-start-learning-to-create-iphone-apps)

I only know basic Python as far as programing languages go.

What do I need to learn to start developing iPhone apps?

I learned part python with almost only learnpythonthehardway.org 
and that wasn't too difficult. I am confident I can learn how to make apps but need to know where to continue. i asked around where to start and people said to learn python so i did but now what to do after that.

I have the newest MBP to work on.

I don't have much interest in the app store i just want to have some fun and stuff like this is what i enjoy doing

I realize people say this is a duplicate someone changed my title and didn't read what i had to say here I want to know where i would continue mostly all other things about this have been closed as well so its hard to get answers

Comment: It's a good start..Keep going..

Comment: @petert use `[link text](http://whatever)` for posting links in comments.

Comment: How can you learn in less than a week with LPTHW while exercise 36 alone asks you to write a game and "Spend _a week_ on it making it as interesting as possible" ?

Comment: Please search through existing questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginning+iphone+development

Comment: I did up to exercise 26 and all i want to know is what to do next people told me to learn python first but i am curious what to do after that

Comment: @Shameer: whoever suggested that you learn Python has no idea what they're talking about. iPhone apps are almost always written in Objective C, and trying to write them in Python instead will almost certainly lead to frustration.

Comment: @agf [OT] Links in questions are transformed, it is counter-intuitive and user-unfriendly to see [links in comments not enhanced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16609/feature-request-when-posting-links-to-same-site-in-comment-display-question-text/16613#16613)

Comment: @Wooble they wanted me to learn it to make learning objective c easier  i plan on learning objective c as well but python first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of programming. Seriously, as you've probably seen it can be a lot of fun.  Starting young is the way to go!

iPhone development is going to be harder than learning the basics of Python, but not unachievable.

One of the problems that you are going to have, is that the tools are not as widely available or as free as Python.  You will need:

1. A mac of some sort (must have an intel processor too, so not an old mac)
2. An iPhone developer account ($99 a year)
3. A copy of XCode (comes free with the account)

Then you need a good book, i used 'Beginning iPhone 4 Development" which has an introduction to objective-c in it.

If that sounds a bit too expensive for something you're not sure you'd enjoy - you could try downloading a free objective-c compiler and learning the language first before committing to  that stuff.

Comment: could i use the xcode that is free in mac app store i have a new MBP to use

Comment: i presume that is an older version of xcode if it is free - xcode 4.1 targeting iOS is not free unless you have a developer account.  Hey, try downloading it and see.

Comment: Downloaded it , lets me make stuff but i guess i cant test it on an actual iphone but looks like ios simulator is included

Comment: Just checked, the free one is XCode 3.x - it can only target iOS 3.0 or earlier - but there's no reason why working with the simulator you can't learn the basics to see whether its worth spending $99.  Don't forget to accept one of the answers if it was helpful.

Comment: it says 4.1.1 in the app store

Comment: and how do i accept an answer  never mind found it

Comment: Hey, even better - good luck.  It will be harder work than Python, but stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Start at http://developer.apple.com. From there, download the iOS SDK. iOS apps are mostly written in another language called Objective-C and a framework called Cocoa Touch.